# Vertical dropdown Menu with submenu showing on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I want to make a vertical dropdown menu with the following structure(for each "button" a different "dropdown" div).The idea is when I hover "button", the "dropdown" to appear **over the "button" with the same size** ( the "dropdown" shrinks to the "button" size with equal heights "subnav1" ) or to appear **left to the "dropdown"** ( again with equal heights "subnav1" ). The problem, however , is that I can't make the "dropdown" *display:block*s on "button" hover and ,in the second case, the "button" to be hovered while selecting "subnav1" element.
**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav1">
        <li class="button"><div class="subnav">BUTTON1</div></li>
        <li class="button"><div class="subnav">BUTTON2</div></li>
        <li class="button"><div class="subnav">BUTTON3</div><li>
        <li class="button"><div class="subnav">BUTTON4</div></li>
        <li class="button"><div class="subnav">BUTTON5</div></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <A href="#" class="subnav1">SUBBUTTON1</a>
        <A href="#" class="subnav1">SUBBUTTON1</a>
        <A href="#" class="subnav1">SUBBUTTON1</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 1vm;
    float:left;
    height:450px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#a56d3b;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:right;
}
.nav a{
    text-decoration:none;

}
.subnav{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FCFBE3;
    font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
    font-size:1.3em;
    display:block;
}
.button{
    border-bottom:1PX DOTTED #FFECBA;
    border-right:1PX DOTTED #FFECBA;
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
    padding:2em 0 0 0 ;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.button:last-child{
    border-bottom:0px;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.dropdown{
    height:89px;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 180px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.subnav1{
    height:30px;
    width:180px;
    padding:5px 0;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#D8A06E;
        DISPLAY:BLOCK;
}
.subnav1:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.nav.nav1 .button:hover .dropdown{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using absolutely wrong markup of the HTML navigation, correct  and valid structure is:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">1st Level</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">1st Level</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">1st Level</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2nd Level</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and then it is easy as a pie, just styling:

```
.nav {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vtt0qnpt/

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you want it to be. Let me know if this is not the result you are looking for

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #E61094;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 115px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a{
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #9E1192
}

.nav:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.nav:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #F576EA;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Subbutton 1</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 2</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <butoon class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Subbutton 1</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 2</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <butoon class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Subbutton 1</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 2</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <butoon class="dropbtn">Dropdown 4</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Subbutton 1</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 2</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <butoon class="dropbtn">Dropdown 5</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Subbutton 1</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 2</a>
   <a href="#">Subbutton 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i want to do, the problem is I can't make the primary menu button to open/close on hover the submenu

Comment: I think the above code should work then @AllaKonstantinova

Comment: @AllaKonstantinova If my answer helped you, please approve it. Thanks.